# Python Changing value of XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Hello im using lxml to try and change the value of a specific xml element.  Here is my code.

```
directory = '/Users/eeamesX/work/data/expert/EFTlogs/20160725/IT'
XMLParser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    if f.endswith(".xml"):

        xmlfile = directory + '/' + f
        tree = etree.parse(xmlfile, parser=XMLParser)
        root = tree.getroot()
        hardwareRevisionNode = root.find(".//hardwareRevision")

        if hardwareRevisionNode.text == "5":
            print " "
            print hardwareRevisionNode.text
            str(hardwareRevisionNode.text) == "DVT3"
            print hardwareRevisionNode.text
```

I want to change the 5 to a DVT3  instead it just prints it out below as 5 and 5.  I referenced [Change xml using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728719/change-xml-using-python) .  Unfortunately it doesnt work for me.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you can make your code a bit simpler by using the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

Comment: Perhaps for future audiences, you could show a better way.  The point of stackoverflow is to build a library of knowledge for improvement in coding.  Plus im curious :)

Comment: `xmlfiles = glob('/Users/eeamesX/work/data/expert/EFTlogs/20160725/IT/*.xml')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you need assignment `=` not comparison `==` and the cast to string `str()` is unnecessary.  once you've assigned the value, you'll want to write the result back out to the file:

```
hardwareRevisionNode.text = "DVT3"

outfile = open(xmlfile, 'w')
oufile.write(etree.tostring(tree))
outfile.close()
```

good luck!

Comment: It was the = sign, as stated in your first part of your answer.  Thank you sir.  Im so used to writing ==