# Extract an attribute value , Lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I have the following Xml file:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\r\n<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14"><w:body><w:p w:rsidR="00706A37" w:rsidRPr="004A1CE5" w:rsidRDefault="004A1CE5"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="12"/><w:numId w:val="0"/></w:numPr><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/><w:szCs w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/><w:r w:rsidRPr="004A1CE5"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/><w:szCs w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>H</w:t></w:r><w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/><w:r w:rsidR="00A23794"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="CommentReference"/>
```

And I need to extract the value of `id` within a `<w:commentRangeStart>` tag . I have looked over many questions on SO and found the following type:

I tried:
(iterate over every p with a commentRangeStart tag , and retrieve attrib. This returned nothing.

```
for p in lxml_tree.xpath('.//w:p/commentRangeStart',namespaces = {'w':w}):
    print p.attrib
```

I tried various combinations with `'commentRangeStart[@id]'` and `commentRangeStart/@id` but None worked. I referred to many questions and one of them is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171146/python-lxml-modify-attributes) .
I would prefer a way in which it would go over every p and then search for the comment tag. Like:

```
for p in lxml_tree.xpath('.//w:p',namespaces = {'w':w}):  
    p.xpath(./w:commentRangeStart/...)
```

and so on..

What's wrong with my expression.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify namespace:

```
for p in root.xpath('.//w:p/w:commentRangeStart', namespaces={'w':w}):
    print p.attrib
```

output:

```
{'{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}id': '0'}
```

---

Alternative:

```
for id_ in root.xpath('.//w:p/w:commentRangeStart/@w:id', namespaces={'w': w}):
    print id_
```

output:

```
0
```

Comment: can i replace the extra w's with // ??

Comment: @Swordy, If you replace it, you will get empty element list.

Comment: could you add the code for a 2 level iteration ? I tried this:  for p in lxml_tree.xpath('.//w:p/w', namespaces={'w':w}):
    for id_ in p.xpath('./w:commentRangeStart/@w:id',namespaces={'w':w}):
        print id_ 
but doesn't print anything..

Comment: the reason is that I need to carry out an operation for every p irrespective of whether it has a comment tag or not..

Comment: @Swordy, http://asciinema.org/a/12781 (BTW, the given xml is not complete. So I added closing tags.)

Comment: @Swordy, Do you mean? `for id_ in root.xpath('.//w:p//w:commentRangeStart/@w:id', namespaces={'w': w}): print id_`

Comment: @Swordy, Or `for p in root.xpath('.//w:p', namespaces={'w': w}):
    for id_ in root.xpath('.//w:commentRangeStart/@w:id', namespaces={'w': w}):
        print id_`

Comment: yeah it was too big , just used a sample here.. How should I implement a 2 level iteration? that is , over every p , then find comment tags.. No , my comment used 2 for loops. yes ur 2nd comment.