# Using regex to modify XML

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have to replace some 'file names' from within an XML with the full path for those files. All the files are in the same directory which simplifies things somewhat. I was trying to use BeautifulSoup4 but there was a bug that kept breaking crashing python so I'm trying to do the same thing with regex's.

The copasiML variable contains an XML as a string.

My code:

```
    copasiML=IA.read_copasiML_as_string(copasi_file)
    data_file_names=re.findall('<Parameter name="File Name" type="file" value="(.*)"/>',copasiML)
    for i in data_file_names:
        copasiML2=re.sub('<Parameter name="File Name" type="file" value="'+i+'"/>','<Parameter name="File Name" type="file" value="'+os.path.join(os.getcwd()+i)+'"/>',copasiML)
        os.remove(copasi_file)
        with open(copasi_file,'w') as f:
            f.write(str(copasiML2))
```

As it stands, my code runs but doesn't actually do anything. Would anybody happen to know how to fix my code?

Many thanks

Comment: I'd recommend [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) library or, at least, [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) from standard python

Answer (score 0):

Every time you try to parse HTML/XML with Regular Expressions, you make baby Jesus cry.

I BeautifulSoup doesn't work for you, I suggest XPath as illustrated in [python lxml - modify attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171146/python-lxml-modify-attributes).

Fun (but instructive) readings:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
- [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)
- [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2741780